My project directory name is not single name.How to import module from another directory to parent directory?
I need to import module to main directory from another directory
this is the project hierachy
main.py :
    ```python

    from sub_file import sub_class

    class main:
        def main_method():
            print(sub_class.my_method())

    main.main_method()

    ```

sub_file.py :
    ```python

    from my_module import multiple

    class sub_class:
        def my_method():
            a = 5
            x = 3
            y = 2
            
            return a + multiple(x, y)

    ```

(package_1/) my_module.py :
    ```python

    def multiple(x, y):
        return x * y

    ```


Excuse me sir, actually i need to no how to import module from another directory to parent directory in python. That is why i ask this question .
